# Creating a Harmony that Harmonizes with a Chord

Tags: theory, chords, sheet-music, harmony

I'm trying to get a harmony that will harmonize with my chord, Am.  I want something to harmonize with the A,G,F melody and with Am.  Is there any way to do this?

This is what I have, I would like to add it to the treble line of the accompaniment.

[image]

Comment: Usually, harmonies occur with reference to the preceding and following parts of the music. By posting them too, it'll give more meaning to the question.

Comment: Aminor doesn't seem to be the best fit chord to AGF. Maybe this is why harmony escapes you. Dminor or F seem to fit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. With modern harmonic practice, the underlying harmony can be almost anything you want. Since the melody is related to a minor, this could be relatively simple. If you previously were on an E7 chord and are going to a d minor chord, then you could put an a minor under this melody.

Harmonies, though, occur in context. From the three notes you've given, it's impossible to know what key you're in, where the music is going, where the melody falls in the phrase - all of these determine the harmonic choices. Posting more context will allow for more specific answers.

If you ear doesn't hear the chord as correct, it probably isn't. Try d minor or F major instead.

If you're looking for a melody to go with an a minor chord, again, it depends on the context. Changing to an alternate a minor scale (like harmonic minor) or focusing the melody on the chord tones will help to strengthen the connection between the melody and harmony.